# Jest, Enzyme: Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-dom

I have a `<UserListComponent />` which outputs one `<Contact />` component and list of contacts presentated by `<Contacts />`.

The problem is that in the test for `<UserListComponent />` when I try to mount it, test outputs an error `Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`

`withRouter()` is used in `<Contacts />` component.

How can I mock `ContactsComponent` without router in test of parent component?

I found some similar issue https://www.bountysource.com/issues/49297944-invariant-violation-you-should-not-use-route-or-withrouter-outside-a-router
but it only describes situation when component is cover by `withRouter()` itself, not children.

**UserList.test.jsx**

```
const mockResp = {
  count: 2,
  items: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'User1',
      email: 'email1@gmail.com',
      phone: '+123456',
      online: false
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'User2',
      email: 'email2@gmail.com',
      phone: '+789123',
      online: false
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: 'User3',
      email: 'email3@gmail.com',
      phone: '+258369147',
      online: false
    }
  ],
  next: null
}

describe('UserList', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.resetMocks()
  });

  test('should output list of users', () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(mockResp));

    const wrapper = mount(<UserListComponent user={mockResp.items[2]} />);

    expect(wrapper.find('.contact_small')).to.have.length(3);
  });

})
```

**UserList.jsx**

```
export class UserListComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { users, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Contact
          userName={this.props.user.name}
          content={this.props.user.phone}
        />
        {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : <Contacts type="contactList" user={this.props.user} contacts={users} />}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

**Contacts.jsx**

```
class ContactsComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      error: null,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <SectionTitle title="Contacts" />
        <div className="contacts">
         //contacts
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export const Contacts = withRouter(ContactsComponent);
```

Answer (score 147):

To test a component (with Jest) that contains `<Route>` and `withRouter` you need to import Router in you test, not in your component

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and use it like this

```
app = shallow(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>);
```

Comment: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Header)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Header)".

Comment: @AnupamMaurya use `MemoryRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` and it will work.

Comment: i am getting same error as @AnupamMaurya and i have used `memory router`

Comment: Does this really work with `shallow`? I think `mount` needs to be used

Answer (score 27):

## Utility Function To Wrap Mount With Context

Wrapping mount with Router in tests works, but there are situations where you don't want Router to be the parent component in your mount. Therefore I'm currently injecting context into mount using a wrapper function:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

import { shape } from 'prop-types';

// Instantiate router context
const router = {
  history: new BrowserRouter().history,
  route: {
    location: {},
    match: {},
  },
};

const createContext = () => ({
  context: { router },
  childContextTypes: { router: shape({}) },
});

export function mountWrap(node) {
  return mount(node, createContext());
}

export function shallowWrap(node) {
  return shallow(node, createContext());
}
```

This could be in a file called, say contextWrap.js, in a test helpers directory.

### Example describe block:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TableC } from '../../src/tablec';
import { mountWrap, shallowWrap } from '../testhelp/contextWrap';
import { expectedProps } from './mockdata'

describe('Table', () => {
  let props;
  let component;
  const wrappedShallow = () => shallowWrap(<TableC {...props} />);

  const wrappedMount = () => mountWrap(<TableC {...props} />);

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      query: {
        data: tableData,
        refetch: jest.fn(),
      },
    };
    if (component) component.unmount();
  });

  test('should render with mock data in snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = wrappedShallow();
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('should call a DeepTable with correct props', () => {
    const wrapper = wrappedMount();
    expect(wrapper.find('DeepTable').props()).toEqual(expectedProps);
  });

});
```

You can also use this pattern to wrap subcomponents in other types of context, for example if you are using react-intl, material-ui or your own context types.

Comment: Where is the 'mount' function coming from in the first file?

Comment: It is enzyme's mount - I believe I'm setting it up globally with a jestSetup file before invoking tests that performs 

`import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';` and sets
`global.mount = mount;`. Added to answer for clarification, thanks very much.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I think it is a lot cleaner then using the accepted answers approach.

Comment: @BenLime I agree, this solution allows using `wrapper.setProps`, `wrapper.state`, `wrapper.setState` with no further modification.

Comment: lifesaver. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveBanton still am getting the same issue after using this can u pls help with this

Comment: it's not working for me can anyone help me for this

Answer (score 14):

You need to wrap the `App` with a `BrowserRouter` or an equivalent,
see the below example of simple test case a component App that uses React Router

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

it("renders without crashing", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>,
div
  );
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
})
```

Comment: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(BaseLayout)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(BaseLayout)".

Answer (score 10):

i had same problem, and first comment helped me, but there are a lot of code
i have better way how to resolve this problem.
See my solution below:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import SisuSignIn from '../../../components/Sisu/SisuSignIn.js';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Container = SisuSignIn;

let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(<Container />);
});

describe('SisuSignIn', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('should render one <h1>', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <SisuSignIn auth={{ loading: false }} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find('div').length).toBe(12);
  });
});
```

Comment: This comment should be higher up as it works.

Answer (score 7):

A  keeps the history of your "URL" in memory (does not read or write to the address bar). Useful in tests and non-browser environments like React Native.

I got similar error solution is wrapping component with the help of [Memory router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md)

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router'

<MemoryRouter>
  <App/>
</MemoryRouter>
```

Comment: Yes, for testing MemoryRouter should be preferred instead of BrowserRouter.

Answer (score 7):

Add the Router tag to render it.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"
import CategoriesToBag from "../CategoriesToBag";



describe('Testing CategoriesToBag Component', () => {
    test("check if heading is correct", () => {
        const defaultValue = "Amazing Categories To Bag";
        const wrapper = render(<Router><CategoriesToBag /></Router>);
        expect(wrapper.find('.textBannerTitle').text()).toMatch(/Categories To Bag/);
        expect(wrapper.find('.textBannerTitle').text()).not.toMatch(/Wrong Match/);
        expect(wrapper.find('.textBannerTitle').text()).toBe(defaultValue);
    });

});
```

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

actually i used to create snapshot tests for my components with `react-test-renderer` and i faced with this issue and what i did i just wrap my component with a `BrowserRouter` that ships with `react-router-dom`, you can do so like below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";


import UserListComponent from './whatever'



test('some description', () => {
  
  const props = { ... }

  const jsx = (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserListComponent {...props} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )

  const tree = renderer.create(jsx).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()

})
```

totaly recommend useing a test factory for this kind of situations if you want to test it for multiple times!

Answer (score 0):

So I was thinking about this for ages, and I don't actually care about the implementation of the withRouter (I can assume that just works or test it elsewhere), and so I can just mock that function to return itself (much like I have done for the Link function).

```
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  Link: () => <div />,
  withRouter: (x) => x,
}));
```

I hope this helps someone like it would have helped me several hours ago!